# Passproxy issue in apache - citadel installation

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, email-server, citadel

I am running Apache with several virtualhosts.

To configure Citadel, I am running WebCit along with Apache (which is recommended option by Citadel).

Apache should ideally forward ctdl.example.com to 127.0.0.1:2000.  But apache is not accepting the configuration:

> > ```
> > <VirtualHost *:80>
> >     ServerName ctdl.example.com
> >     ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:2000/
> >     ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:2000/
> > </VirtualHost>
> > ```

But apache is giving error on line 3. Probably because of ProxyPass.

How to fix this?

Comment: Exactly what error did you receive? And what is on line 3?

Comment: it's fixed nw.

but it's giving me 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable now.
hacking the configuration to fix it. 
is there any good how-to reference for running citadel with apache on the side, so i can match the configuration.?

Comment: If Apache gives you an error, you should check the error log.